Excel: Find Duplicates for combined rows
I'm trying to figure out how to find duplicated row combinations.
My data uses text so I've been having a hard time finding a method that works with it.



A
B
C
D




T001
Apple
Apple
Apple


T002
Apple
Banana
Apple


T003
Apple
Apple
Banana


T004
Apple
Mango
Kiwi



So T002 and T003 should count as a duplicate.
I used concatenates in another column, but I later realized that it doesn't account for people putting the combination in a different order.

Sort the data in rows, and then look for duplicates in the sorted data.

use a helper column with a formula similar to =CONCAT(SORT(...)), then sort using this column.

Are you use Excel 2016? If so, the new function Sort is not available. But you can try to copy the data and choose transpose when pasting, sort data for each column. Then use CONCAT function combine the data for each column.

Thank you! My company just updated me to the new Excel, so I didn't know about the Sort Function. It worked perfectly!

Since you seem to have the SORT function, you can possibly use the following:
I created a Table so as to be able to use structured referencing and also ensure that the table the formula would properly adjust if you add/remove rows from the table.
After you create the table, you can create an additional column.
In the first cell of that column, enter the following formula:
=SUM(
    --(
        CONCAT(SORT(Fruits[@[Column2]:[Column4]], , , TRUE)) =
            BYROW(
                Fruits[[Column2]:[Column4]],
                LAMBDA(arr, CONCAT(SORT(arr, 1, 1, TRUE)))
            )
    )
) > 1

The formula will autopopulate the rest of the column and mark whether or not the row is a duplicate:


I'm not sure about the scope of the task, but if installing Power Query is an option, here's a way:

Install Download Microsoft Power Query for Excel from Official Microsoft Download Center

Select the range and insert a table, preferably with a header row

Get it into Power Query: with cursor inside the table, Select Data > Get & Transform Data > From Table/Range.

Add Custom Column, for example SortedValues with the formula
Text.Combine(List.Sort({[B],[C],[D]}))

Select Keep Rows > Keep Duplicates

Exit and Load the data back into Excel (for example in a new sheet)


Power Query Step

Results in Excel

Power Query Steps (automatically created from the steps above)
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content], 
  addSortedValuesCol = Table.AddColumn(
    Source, 
    "SortedValues", 
    each Text.Combine(List.Sort({[B], [C], [D]}))
  ), 
  #"Kept duplicates" = 
    let
      columnNames = {"SortedValues"}, 
      addCount = Table.Group(
        addSortedValuesCol, 
        columnNames, 
        {"Count", Table.RowCount, type number}
      ), 
      selectDuplicates = Table.SelectRows(addCount, each [Count] > 1), 
      removeCount = Table.RemoveColumns(selectDuplicates, "Count")
    in
      Table.Join(addSortedValuesCol, columnNames, removeCount, columnNames, JoinKind.Inner)
in
  #"Kept duplicates"

